# How to construct and add to a data frame with named columns?

Tags: r, dataframe

I cannot figure out how to do this without throwing errors. I have a set of column names for my data frame I want to create and add to that looks like this:

```
x <- c("A", "B", "C")
```

So, I go down through the loop and I calculate some numerical values in a vector, say:

```
z <- c(1, 5, 7, 8, 34, 5)
```

z is the same dimension each time through the loop.

The first time through (or even outside the loop) I want to initialize a data frame by doing something like:

```
df$x[1] <- z
```

so I have a data frame that looks like:

```
   A
1  1
2  5
3  7
4  8
5  34
6  5
```

The next time through the loop I want to add another column to df with a column heading being the second element of x, and a set of new z values. If the data frame has to be completely dimensioned ahead of time, I could calculate variables outside the loop to do this, say, M and N, but these may change from one run to the next.

I cannot seem to figure out how to do this. Suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 set.seed(1)
 #set the column names
 x <- c("A", "B", "C")
 #create the list that later we will convert to a data.frame
 df<-setNames(vector("list",length(x)),x)
 #loop to produce the various z
 for (i in 1:length(x))  {
      #do some stuff to evaluate z
      z<-sample(5)
      #assign to an element of df
      df[[i]]<-z
 }
 #coerce to a data.frame
 df<-as.data.frame(df)
 #  A B C
 #1 2 5 2
 #2 5 4 1
 #3 4 2 3
 #4 3 3 4
 #5 1 1 5
```

Comment: Yes, perfect! I missed on two things: the reassignment of the column names with setNames and the use of the double brackets that isolates the column of df. Thanks!!!